# Fill between standard deviations on Matplotlib lineplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, line-plot

I have a line plot which graphs 2 columns of data loaded from an excel file. See Plot:
[Matplotlib line plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5P2M.png)

I want to display the standard deviation for each line (i.e., column of data) in my plot using the fill between function or something similar (like image 2), however I cannot figure out how to include this. Any help would be great. Please note that I am very new to this...
[How I would like my plot to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZNEW.png)

Here is the code used for my lineplot:

```
import pandas as pd
import scipy as sp
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Probability_fast_gamma_on_theta = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\RL\Excel work\Probability_of_a_theta_cycle_containing_fast_gamma.xlsx')

fig5, ax5=plt.subplots()
plt.plot(Probability_fast_gamma_on_theta.MIA)
plt.plot(Probability_fast_gamma_on_theta.CTL)

plt.grid(False)
plt.ylim(0.0, 0.6)
plt.xlim(0.0, 25)
plt.legend(['MIA', 'CTL'], loc='lower right')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Maybe `plt.errorbar`

Comment: Please refer to the official [reference](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/fill_between_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-fill-between-demo-py).

Answer (score 6):

This is straightforwardly done using the `plt.fill_between()` function. A minimal example would be as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 50)
y = np.sin(x) + np.random.randn(len(x)) * 0.03

yerr0 = y - (0.1 + np.random.randn(len(x)) * 0.03)
yerr1 = y + (0.1 + np.random.randn(len(x)) * 0.03)

ax.plot(x, y, color='C0')
plt.fill_between(x, yerr0, yerr1, color='C0', alpha=0.5)
```